# How to assign same property for all objects (MSForm Controls)?

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

So lets say I have this bit of code:

```
With Me
    Frame1.Visible: Frame2.Visible: Frame3.Visible 'Ect... = False
End With
```

How can you make all the objects listed within `With me` have the same property instead of adding the `.Visible` property to each one?

Comment: Loop through each object in `me`, and set to whatever you need?

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more? What would I use to check for each object when looping? `For Me`?

Comment: What's `me`? A userform? Try searching for "loop through objects in [whatever] VBA" and see if you get any ideas/direction.

Comment: Yes `Me` is a UserForm. Searching around hasn't turned up much. Did find one post talking about looping thru object methods but not object properties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1st Option**

You can do this with

```
With Me
  .Frame1.Visible = True
  .Frame2.Visible = True
  .Frame3.Visible = True
  'etc
End With
```

**2nd Option**

Since you have a series of **control names**. You can loop through them with a variable.

```
Dim iLoop as Integer  '<~ declaring the variable we will use
For iLoop = 1 to 3    '<~ Loop from 1 to 3
  Me.Controls("Frame" & iLoop).Visible = True  '<~ set the .Visible property of each control to true
Next
```

Note that this will return an error if the control is not present in your userform.

**3rd Option**

And if you will frequently loop through this controls, you can add them to a collection and loop through that collection later on runtime.

**1)** First declare a global variable (located in the uppermost of your module/userform code).

```
Private CollectionOfControls as Collection
```

**2)** Add them to this collection with, `UserForm_Initialize`.

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
Dim iLoop As Integer
Set CollectionOfControls = New Collection
With CollectionOfControls
  For iLoop = 1 To 3
    .Add Me.Controls("Frame" & iLoop)
  Next
End Sub
```

**3.a)** Then on runtime you can loop through them like,

```
Sub Caller1()
Dim oEach As Object
For Each oEach In CollectionOfControls
  oEach.Visible = True
  ' do something
Next
End Sub
```

**3.b)** or something like,

```
Sub Caller2()
Dim iLoop As Integer
For iLoop = 1 To CollectionOfControls.Count
  CollectionOfControls.Item(iLoop).Visible = True
  ' do something
Next
End Sub
```

Hope this helps. Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

Easiest way - in my opinion - is to loop through all controls in your form and check type or name to decide what to do like in the following example:

```
For Each c In Me.Controls
    If TypeName(c) = "Frame" Then
        ' do something
    End If
    If c.Name Like "Frame*" Then
        ' do something else
    End If
Next c
```